# Is there such a thing as a reverse Menger Sponge / Carpet?

Tags: geometry, fractals

What I mean is a set similar to the menger sponge/carpet, but expanding, instead of intricate. Iteration $0$, $\ddot m_0$ is the unit cube/square from $0$ to $1$, and the following iterations are described by the following:

$\begin{array}[llclclcl]\\
\ddot m_0 & \ni (x,y) & \iff & 0 < x < 1 & \land & 0 < y < 1 \\
\ddot m_{n + 1} & \ni (x,y) & \iff & 0 < x < 3^{n + 1} & \land & 0 < y < 3^{n + 1} & \land &(x \mathbin{\text{mod}} 3^n, y \mathbin{\text{mod}} 3^n) \in \ddot m_n\\
\end{array}$

Does the set $\ddot m_\infty = \lim_{n \to \infty} \ddot m_n$ exist, have any special properties or is in any other way relevant? Most importantly, however, is it a fractal, and, if it's a known set, what is its name?

Comment: In what sense are you defining the limiting object?  What do you mean by the term "fractal"?  What kind of properties are you interested in?

Comment: Is its Hausdorff Dimension larger than its topological dimension, and has this shape a name?

Comment: Near as I can tell, the set you describe is composed of squares in $\mathbb{R}^2$, each of which has dimension 2 (topological and Hausdorff).  So no, not a fractal.  As for a name:  how about Sally?

Comment: TGlad defines negative dimensions for shapes like this: https://tglad.blogspot.com/2017/08/reframing-geometry-to-include-negative.html